# Regex to find all matches linewise where text1("abc") is present and text2("xyz") is not present anywhere in each line

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Regex to find all matches linewise where text1("abc") is present and text2("xyz") is not present anywhere in each line.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Ahh... Now I get it. Good one :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your order ;)

Eg.

```
^(?!.*xyz).*abc.*
```

should do the trick.

It uses a negative look-ahead to make sure the line doesn't contain the text "xyz", followed by a test any text up to "abc". And to match the whole line, followed by any text.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VX2pOG/1).